# SQL injection, where to look for changes

Tags: sql, mysqli

I've an area on my website where a selection of products are shown. These are searchable via dropdown menus it uses a database. Unfortunately an SQL injection has been found and i've been requested to address any vulnerabilities. The SQL queries that have been flagged as suspicious/malicious are here. I'm a novice with SQL so not sure what to look for, can anyone help?

```
------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT sale_item.*, manufacturer.name AS "mfr_name",
boom_type.name AS "boomType", lift_model.working_height,
lift_model.name AS "modelName", category.name AS
"category_name" FROM sale_item INNER JOIN manufacturer ON
sale_item.manufacturer_id = manufacturer.id INNER JOIN
lift_model ON sale_item.model_id = lift_model.id INNER JOIN
boom_type ON lift_model.boom_type_id = boom_type.id INNER
JOIN category ON lift_model.category_id = category.id WHERE
manufacturer.id = '-6380' OR (ORD(MID((SELECT
IFNULL(CAST(schema_name AS CHAR),0x20) FROM (SELECT
DISTINCT(schema_name) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA LIMIT
1,1) AS eifp),2,1))>64) AND 'PyIX'='PyIX' AND boom_type.id =
'4' LIMIT 0, 12
------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT sale_item.*, manufacturer.name AS "mfr_name",
boom_type.name AS "boomType", lift_model.working_height,
lift_model.name AS "modelName", category.name AS
"category_name" FROM sale_item INNER JOIN manufacturer ON
sale_item.manufacturer_id = manufacturer.id INNER JOIN
lift_model ON sale_item.model_id = lift_model.id INNER JOIN
boom_type ON lift_model.boom_type_id = boom_type.id INNER
JOIN category ON lift_model.category_id = category.id WHERE
manufacturer.id = '-6380' OR (ORD(MID((SELECT
IFNULL(CAST(schema_name AS CHAR),0x20) FROM (SELECT
DISTINCT(schema_name) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA LIMIT
1,1) AS eifp),2,1))>77) AND 'PyIX'='PyIX' AND boom_type.id =
'4' LIMIT 0, 12
```

** EDIT FORM SUBMIT PART

```
<form action="hire-equipment.php5" method="get">
   <div class="headings">Manufacturer</div>
   <select id="manufacturer" name="manufacturer">
     <option value="any">Any Manufacturer</option>
        <?php
        // Retrieve all the manufacturers and add to the pull-down menu.
        $query = "SELECT id, name FROM manufacturer ORDER BY name ASC";     
        $tmpresult = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($tmpresult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<option value=\"{$row['id']}\">{$row['name']}</option>\n";
        }
        ?>
   </select>

<div class="headings">Type</div>
   <select id="boom" name="boom">
     <option value="any">Any Type</option>
        <?php
        // Retrieve all the boom types and add to the pull-down menu.
        $query = "SELECT id, name FROM boom_type ORDER BY name ASC";        
        $tmpresult = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($tmpresult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<option value=\"{$row['id']}\">{$row['name']}</option>\n";
        }
        ?>
   </select>  


<div class="headings">Power Source</div>
   <select id="category" name="category">
     <option value="any">Any Power Source</option>
        <?php
        // Retrieve all the categories and add to the pull-down menu.
        $query = "SELECT id, name FROM category ORDER BY name ASC";     
        $tmpresult = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($tmpresult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<option value=\"{$row['id']}\">{$row['name']}</option>\n";
        }
        ?>
   </select>  



<div class="headings">Working Height </div>
   <select id="working_height" name="working_height">
     <option value="0">Any Height</option>
     <option value="1">up to 10m</option>
     <option value="2">11m > 20</option>
     <option value="3">Above 21</option>
   </select>  



<div class="headings">Price</div>
   <select id="price" name="price">
     <option value="ASC">Low > High</option>
     <option value="DESC">High > Low</option>
   </select>  




<div class="headings">Search</div>
   <input name="search" type="text" size="20" />
</div>

<div id="findmachine">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />

    <input src="../images/submit.png" type='image' value="Update Results"    /> 
</div>


</form>
```

** END EDIT FORM SUBMIT

```
if (isset($_GET['submitted'])) { // Check if the form has been submitted.

$searches = 'manufacturer=' . $_GET['manufacturer'] . '&boom=' . $_GET['boom'] . '&category=' . $_GET['category'] . '&working_height=' . $_GET['working_height'] . '&price=' . $_GET['price'] . '&submitted=TRUE';

$query = "SELECT sale_item.*, manufacturer.name AS \"mfr_name\", boom_type.name AS \"boomType\", lift_model.working_height, lift_model.name AS \"modelName\", category.name AS \"category_name\" FROM sale_item INNER JOIN manufacturer ON sale_item.manufacturer_id = manufacturer.id INNER JOIN lift_model ON sale_item.model_id = lift_model.id INNER JOIN boom_type ON lift_model.boom_type_id = boom_type.id INNER JOIN category ON lift_model.category_id = category.id"; 


if (isset($_GET['manufacturer'])) {
    $mfr  = $_GET['manufacturer'];
    if ($mfr != "any") {
        $whereclause .= " manufacturer.id = '$mfr'";
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
    $cat = $_GET['category'];
    if ($cat != "any") {
        if ($whereclause)
            $whereclause .= " AND ";
        $whereclause .= "category.id = '$cat'";
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['boom'])) {
    $boom = $_GET['boom'];
    if ($boom != "any") {
        if ($whereclause)
            $whereclause .= " AND ";
        $whereclause .= "boom_type.id = '$boom'";
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['year'])) {
    $year = $_GET['year'];
    if ($year != "any") {
        if ($whereclause)
            $whereclause .= " AND ";
        $whereclause .= "sale_item.mf_year = $year";
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['working_height'])) {
    $wh = $_GET['working_height'];
    switch ($wh) {
        case 1: $whu = 10; $whl = 1;
            break;
        case 2: $whu = 20; $whl = 11;
            break;
        case 3: $whu = 1000; $whl = 21;
            break;
    }
    if ($whl && $whu) {
        if ($whereclause)
            $whereclause .= " AND ";
        $whereclause .= "lift_model.working_height >= $whl AND  lift_model.working_height <= $whu";
    }
}
    if (isset($_GET['search']) && (strlen($_GET['search']) > 0)) {
    $search = escape_data($_GET['search']);
        if ($whereclause)
            $whereclause .= " OR ";
        $whereclause .= "manufacturer.name LIKE '%$search%' OR     boom_type.name LIKE '%$search%' OR category.name LIKE '%$search%' OR     lift_model.name LIKE '%$search%'";

}

if ($whereclause)
    $query = $query . " WHERE " . $whereclause;


if (isset($_GET['price'])) {
    $post = $_GET['price'];
    $query .= " ORDER BY sale_item.price_pounds $post ";
}

// Determine how many pages there are. 
if (isset($_GET['np'])) { // Already been determined.
    $num_pages = $_GET['np'];
} else { // Need to determine.

    // Count the number of records
    $tmpresult = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $query);
    $num_records = mysqli_num_rows ($tmpresult);
    mysqli_free_result ($tmpresult); // Free up the resources.  

    // Calculate the number of pages.
    if ($num_records > $display) { // More than 1 page.
        $num_pages = ceil ($num_records/$display);
    } else {
        $num_pages = 1;
    }
   }

// Determine where in the database to start returning results.
if (isset($_GET['s'])) {
    $start = $_GET['s'];
} else {
    $start = 0;
}

$query .= " LIMIT $start, $display";
 //echo '<h2>' . $row['boomType'] . '</h2>'; 
//echo "$query<br />";

} else {
$searches = null;
// Determine how many pages there are. 
if (isset($_GET['np'])) { // Already been determined.
    $num_pages = $_GET['np'];
} else { // Need to determine.

    // Count the number of records
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sale_item";
    $tmpresult = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($tmpresult, MYSQLI_NUM);
    $num_records = $row[0];
    mysqli_free_result ($tmpresult); // Free up the resources.  

    // Calculate the number of pages.
    if ($num_records > $display) { // More than 1 page.
        $num_pages = ceil ($num_records/$display);
    } else {
        $num_pages = 1;
    }
}

//echo "there were $num_records records and the number of pages is     $num_pages<br />\n";

// Determine where in the database to start returning results.
if (isset($_GET['s'])) {
    $start = $_GET['s'];
} else {
    $start = 0;
}

// pull them all
$query = "SELECT sale_item.*, manufacturer.name AS \"mfr_name\", boom_type.name AS \"boomType\", lift_model.name AS \"modelName\", lift_model.working_height, category.name AS \"category_name\" FROM sale_item JOIN manufacturer ON sale_item.manufacturer_id = manufacturer.id JOIN lift_model ON sale_item.model_id = lift_model.id JOIN boom_type ON lift_model.boom_type_id = boom_type.id JOIN category ON lift_model.category_id = category.id LIMIT $start, $display";
}

echo '<div class="clear"></div>';

//echo "$query<br />\n";
$result = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $query);

if (!$result) {
echo "<p><font color=\"red\">It's all gone pear-shaped. Sorry :-(</font></p><br    />";
echo "$query<br />\n";

mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection.

die;
}

$total_records = mysqli_num_rows ($result);
```

Comment: For SQL injection, there has to be a part where a user enters something that goes to your database. I don't see any of that happening here.

Answer (score 0):

Before worrying about MySQL injections, your code needs to show where and how the data being supplied is input/sent to the database.

None of that is visible in your code.

For example :  (assuming you are gathering a user's data from a form/questionnaire)

```
 $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
```

I don't see this in your PHP code.

Please, show it to us, so we can assist you better

Comment: I have edited to show most if not all the code to hopefully provide a fuller picture

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken, but..........your code only shows how you a RETRIEVING data from your database..........not how you are SENDING data there

Comment: Sorry, i've added the code where the options are selected and sent

Comment: Des Bank, you are still missing the point.  Yes, you have displayed the "Form", which is collecting the data.  But...........how is the data being SENT to the database ????

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your question.  You ARE sending data to the database, right ??